# Near perfect hash for guid tostring as dictionary key

Tags: c#, .net

what Im trying to solve: using a guid string as a key for Dictionary(string, someObject) and I want *perfect* hashing on the key...

not sure if Im missing something... When I run the following test with the dictionary constructor only passing in size allocation I get +- 10 collisions each run. When I pass in the IEqualityComparer just calling gethashcode on the string I have the test passing all good! with multiple runs using x = 10 iterations in some cases and y upto a million! I thought the dictionary was adjusting the hashing function especially when dealing with strings? I don't have reflector on my machine :( so I cant check tonight... If you comment out the alternating dictionary initialisations youll see... the test runs relatively quick on my i7.

```
            [TestMethod]
    public void NearPerfectHashingForGuidStrings()
    {
        int y = 100000;
        int collisions = 0;

        //Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>(y, new GuidStringHashing());
        Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>(y);
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {

            Enumerable.Range(1, y).ToList().ForEach((h) =>
            {
                list[Guid.NewGuid().ToString()] = h.ToString();
            });

            var hashDuplicates = list.Keys.GroupBy(h => h.GetHashCode())
                .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                .Select(group => group.Key).ToList();

            hashDuplicates.ToList().ForEach(v => Debug.WriteLine( x +  "--- " + v));
            collisions += hashDuplicates.Count();
            list.Clear();
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(0, collisions);
    }

        public class GuidStringHashing : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is fundamentally impossible.  You cannot have a unique hash for every 128-bit GUID in 32 bits.

Comment: @SLaks that does make sense, but if Im only specifying 100000 items and running the test a couple of hundred times then 'fundamentally' it can pass everytime?

Comment: what I mean is that the test can pass using the IEqualityComparer passed in, right now it fails using the defualt hashing function in the dictionary everytime which is more in line with your pigeonhole comment. I would expect at least 1 collision after 2,147,483,647 items due to the int32 hashcode, but Im only dealing with 100000 as per the test so it should be possible to get a 'near' perfect hash on this domain space, i wash a bit shocked when calling gethashcode on the string was way better than the default dictionary hashing

Comment: The default dictionary hashing simply calls GetHashCode() for the keys. If the key is a string, it will call string.GetHashCode(). Your testing must be erroneous if you came to the conclusion that they are different.

Comment: Also, of interest is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack. According to the table near the end, for a 32-bit hash function the number of hash codes required to have a more than 50% chance of one collision is just 77,000. With 100,000 you are likely to have several collisions.

Comment: Matthew Watson is entirely correct; your expectation is completely out of line with reality. I have a graph of the probability of more than one collision after n 32 bit hashes here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions.aspx -- as you can see, the chance of one collision is already over 1% at only 10000 hashes, and well over 50% at 100000.

Answer (score 2):

Your test is broken.

Because your equality comparer incorrectly reports that two different GUIDs that happen to have the same hash are equal, your dictionary never stores the collisions in the first place.

Due to the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_Principle), it is fundamentally impossible to create a 32-bit perfect hash for more than 2<sup>32</sup> items.

Comment: the test above is not using my IEqualityComparer, its commented out?

Comment: Your comment "When I pass in the IEqualityComparer just calling gethashcode on the string I have the test passing all good" implies that you used the faulty equality comparer and - because it was faulty - came to an incorrect conclusion.

Comment: His test code is not beautiful, but it does establish that when you create 100,000 GUIDs, convert them to strings, and then call `.GetHashCode()` on the strings, then statistically, there will be collisions.

Comment: Also, since "having the same hash code" is an equivalence relation, it is "legal" to identify all strings with the same hash code, that is to consider the equivalence classes of GUIDs _modulo_ hash code, and this is what the `IEqualityComparer<>` does. If his equality comparer didn't identify some strings that weren't identical (inder the usual string comparison), it would be just the standard identity comparer on string, and then he didn't have to write it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. You want a perfect hash function for an unknown set of keys. You can [create perfect hash functions for *specific* set of keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). You can't create one perfect hash function that will work on all sets of keys.

The reason is the "Two Jesus Principle", as was so nicely put by Mark Knopfler: "Two men say they're jesus, one of them must be wrong." (it's more widely known as the "pigeonhole principle")

Comment: I just commented back to Slaks and should have been a bit clearer on the domain input size - its only 100000 items as per the test - if you read my comment earlier to SLaks it should be possible, and Im just a bit shocked that calling gethashcode on the string is way better than the default hash function? ps +1 for the 'Mark Knopfler' ref!

Comment: If you are basing your conclusion on your tests with the GuidStringHashing class from your post above, then you are using a broken comparer. In that case, your results would therefore be meaningless.

Comment: Yes, but you don't know which 100,000 items. You can only generate a perfect hash function on a known set of 100,000 items. Perfect hash functions are useful when you try to retrieve data quickly from a dictionary   - you spend time creating them, so that retrieval is fast.

Comment: @MatthewWatson why is the comparer broken?

Comment: @zmbq that does make sense when thinking of the whole range of guids, I did try to write something with domain input: 36 chars, acsii code 45 (-) and 97 to 122, hashing against high primes on item space of 100000 and was getting the same amount of collisions as the default dictionary, then I tried the string gethashcode on the comparer and the test started passing.

Comment: The comparer is broken because it can return true for two strings which have the same hash code but are in fact different. It should return false if the strings differ, regardless of whether their hash codes are the same. Using it will make it seem as if you never get any collisions in the dictionary (which is what you are seeing!)

Comment: @MatthewWatson I wasn't paying attention to the equals only the gethashcode, let me recheck it...

Comment: @MatthewWatson it is randomly calling equals a few times per 100000, but does now show collisions, it must be calling it on case per collision? not sure on this but my IEqualityComparer now causes my test to fail just with equals running the basic string compare. thanks

Comment: @MatthewWatson When you write a new equality comparer by hand, you _want_ some objects that are not equal under the standard comparer, to be considered equal by your new comparer. Otherwise there wouldn't be a point of making the new comparer. The comparer is not broken.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by a perfect hash code?

Your code is somewhat confusing, especially because you post a class `GuidStringHashing` that is not used by your test method.

But your code demonstrates that when you make 100,000 GUIDs, convert them all to strings, and then take the hash code of the strings, then it happens quite often that not all hash codes are distinct. That might be surprising when there are more than 4 billion integers to choose between, and you only generate 100,000 strings.

You're using the `GetHashCode()` for general strings, but your strings are not too general, they're all something like

```
"2315c2a7-7d29-42b1-9696-fe6a9dd72ffd"
```

so maybe your hash code is not optimal. It's better to parse the strings `h` back to a GUID and use the hash code of that, as in `(new Guid(h)).GetHashCode()`.

However this still gives collisions with 100,000 GUIDs. I think what you're seeing is just the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Try this more simple code. Here I use `GetHashCode()` on the GUIDs, so we expect that the integers are quite random:

```
        var set = new HashSet<int>();
        for (int i = 1; true; ++i)
        {
            if (!set.Add(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()))
                Console.WriteLine("Collision, i is: " + i);
        }
```

We see (by running the above code many times) that a collision almost always happens before 100,000 hash codes have been calculated.